# how to exception for invalid date ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to know to what exception name I should refer to. I am getting invalid date. I checked the docs and I couldn't find it.

```
Begin
    Date.new(day,month,year)
Rescue exceptionname
    statements
```

Comment: The easiest way to figure out what sort of exception you need to add is to generate the error and look at Ruby's output. You can do this inside IRB usually, or do it from the running script.

Comment: It is hard to determine which error type you are trying to rescue, due to the possible errors of each local variable (or method) `day`, `month`, `year` not being defined.  ArgumentError if they are defined bout out of a reasonable range for a valid date, such as the 37th day of a month. Otherwise you may need to give more information.

Comment: What you have is not valid Ruby. What’s the exact code and error you’re getting?

Comment: In this case, the error is the code, really.  But yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`ArgumentError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/ArgumentError.html). Using [`irb`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html):

```
> Date.new(2,-200, 3)

ArgumentError: invalid date
    from (irb):11:in `new'
    from (irb):11
```

so

```
begin
    Date.new(2,-200, 3)
rescue ArgumentError
    #your logic
end
```

Comment: we can use `Date::Error` as well.